# Vim and clang_complete, how to explicitly request to reparse my code

Tags: vim, clang, clang-complete

I use Vim with clang_complete for omnicompletion.

The plugin is automatically triggered when I need completion, e.g., after I type `.` or `->` to access an object members or methods (see screenshot below).

[image: clang_complete showing std::map methods]

The plugin works really nice, however I would need a way to trigger it manually (i.e. to compile my code for syntax checking).

This is useful for two reasons:

1. Static syntax checking
2. Clear previous errors which have been fixed (which otherwise will remain in their buffer). See the two screenshots below for a better understanding.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

---

### Screenshot 1

---

[image: Error at line 3]

---

### Screenshot 2

---

[image: Error fixed]

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the clang_complete docs:

```
        *clang_complete-periodic_quickfix*
        *g:clang_periodic_quickfix*
If equal to 1, it will periodically update the quickfix window.
Default: 0
Note: You could use the g:ClangUpdateQuickFix() to do the same with a mapping.
```

If you set this variable to 1, it would update the quickfix window periodically, (and) or you could create a mapping thus:

```
nmap <leader>uq :call g:ClangUpdateQuickFix()
```

so that \uq would cause the update.  (of course, using YOUR leader mapping, naturally)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for syntax checking on the fly, I suggest you have a look at [syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic),
which basically runs g++ --fsyntaxonly on your code and marks the errors on your buffer.
You can also configure it to use clang!